# How to identify session bean as Stateful or Stateless in EJB 2.x?

Tags: java, ejb, jdeveloper, ejb-2.x

I'm working on migration project from EJB 2.x to 3.1. As there are no annotations in EJB 2.x, I'm unable to identify whether session bean is staeful or stateless.

Below is one of the session bean in the application:

```
package com.guycarp.fac.casualty.ejb.copyFacAccount;

import javax.ejb.*;
import weblogic.ejb.*;

import com.guycarp.common.gcerror.GCException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import com.guycarp.fac.casualty.facManager.*;
import com.guycarp.fac.casualty.ejb.company.EBCompany.*; 
import com.guycarp.common.util.*;
import com.guycarp.fac.casualty.util.*;

/**
 * @ejbgen:session enable-call-by-reference="true" default-transaction="Supports"
 *   ejb-name = "SBCopyFacAccount"
 *
 * @ejbgen:jndi-name local="ejb.SBCopyFacAccountLocalHome"
 *   remote = "ejb.SBCopyFacAccountRemoteHome"
 *
 * @ejbgen:file-generation remote-class = "true" remote-class-name="SBCopyFacAccountRemote" remote-home = "true" remote-home-name="SBCopyFacAccountRemoteHome" local-class="true" local-class-name="SBCopyFacAccount" local-home="true" local-home-name="SBCopyFacAccountHome"
 */
public class SBCopyFacAccountBean
  extends GenericSessionBean
  implements SessionBean
{
  public void ejbCreate() {
    // Your code here
  }

  private SessionContext m_ctx = null;

    protected final String SBCOPY_JDBC_URL = "COPYACCOUNT_JDBC_URL";
    protected final String CLASS_NAME = "com.guycarp.fac.casualty.ejb.copyFacAccount.SBCopyFacAccountBean";
    private EBCompanyHome          m_EBCompanyHome           =  null;



    /**
     * @ejbgen:local-method
     * @ejbgen:remote-method
    */
    public String copyAccount(String p_OldCedantCompany, String p_OldFacAccountNumber , Double p_OldFacAccountVersion,
                            String p_NewCedantCompany, String p_UserId, 
                            BigDecimal idSubmission,Boolean isCedant,String lines, String renewal) throws GCException
    {

        Connection conn = null;
        CallableStatement cs = null;        
        //UserTransaction utx = null;
        String newFacAccountNumber=null;

        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            /** Using the new procedure for getUID which has an OUTPUT Parameter.
            */      
            //utx = m_ctx.getUserTransaction();
            //utx.begin();
            //System.out.println("lines " + lines);
            cs = conn.prepareCall("{call procCopyFacAccount(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,"+lines+",?,?,?)}");
            //System.out.println("p_OldCedantCompany " + p_OldCedantCompany);
            cs.setString(1,p_OldCedantCompany);
            //System.out.println("p_OldFacAccountNumber " + p_OldFacAccountNumber);
            cs.setString(2,p_OldFacAccountNumber);
            //System.out.println("p_OldFacAccountVersion " + p_OldFacAccountVersion);
            cs.setDouble(3,p_OldFacAccountVersion.doubleValue());
            //System.out.println("p_NewCedantCompany " + p_NewCedantCompany);
            cs.setString(4,p_NewCedantCompany);
            cs.setString(5,"FacExchange");
            cs.setString(6,"SBCopyFacAccount");
            //System.out.println("p_UserId " + p_UserId);
            cs.setString(7,p_UserId);   
            //System.out.println("idSubmission " + idSubmission);            
            cs.setBigDecimal(8,idSubmission); 
            if (isCedant != null) {
            //System.out.println("cedant");
                if (isCedant.booleanValue()) {
                    //System.out.println("cedant true");
                        cs.setInt(9,1);   
                } else {
                    //System.out.println("cedant false");
                        cs.setInt(9,0);     
                }               
            }                                                
            cs.setString(10,renewal);                                
            cs.registerOutParameter(11,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);  
            cs.registerOutParameter(12,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);  


            boolean b = cs.execute();   //HRH 2002-08-19 : Unused local variable
            int i = cs.getUpdateCount();//  HRH 2002-08-19 : Unused local variable          

            String ErrorMessage = cs.getString(11);
            //System.out.println("ErrorMessage= " + ErrorMessage);
            newFacAccountNumber = cs.getString(12);

            //System.out.println("SBCopyFacAccountBean newFacAccountNumber " + newFacAccountNumber);
            if ( ErrorMessage != null && !ErrorMessage.equals("") ) {
                throw new GCException( new Exception(ErrorMessage), ErrorMessage, false, false);                
            }

            //utx.commit();
            //utx = null;

        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            GCUtility.errorInfo(e.getMessage());
            throw new GCException( e, "Exception thrown in copyAccount.", false, false);
        } finally {
            /*
            if ( utx!= null ) {
                try {
                    utx.rollback();
                } catch ( Exception e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();                    
                    throw new GCException( e, "Exception thrown in copyAccount.", false, false);
                }
            }
            */
            try {
                if ( cs != null ) cs.close();               
                if ( conn != null ) conn.close();
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                GCUtility.errorInfo(e.getMessage());
                throw new GCException( e, "Exception thrown in copyAccount.", false, false);
            }
        }
        //before sending this newFacAccountNumber  back, set the optprimary for this account as 1.
        if (newFacAccountNumber != null) {

            newFacAccountNumber= newFacAccountNumber.trim();
            String accountNumber = p_OldCedantCompany + " " + newFacAccountNumber   + " " + FacConstant.FACACCOUNTVERSION_01;
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement stmt= null;
            try {
                String sql = "UPDATE TBLFACACCOUNT SET OPTACCOUNTPRIMARY = 1 WHERE CDEFACACCOUNTNUMBER="+newFacAccountNumber
                +" and UIDCEDANTCOMPANY = "+getEBCompany(p_NewCedantCompany) +" and NUMFACACCOUNTVERSION="+FacConstant.FACACCOUNTVERSION_01;

                con = getConnection();
                stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                int success = stmt.executeUpdate();

            }   catch (Exception    e) {
                GCUtility.errorInfo("Exception in copy account bean"+e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return newFacAccountNumber ;
    }


    /**
     * @ejbgen:local-method
     * @ejbgen:remote-method
    */
    public void copyAccount(BigDecimal idSubmission, String newCedantCompany, 
                           String userId) throws GCException {


        Connection conn = null;
        CallableStatement cs = null;        
        //UserTransaction utx = null;

        try {
            conn = getConnection();

            /** Using the new procedure for getUID which has an OUTPUT Parameter.
            */      
            //utx = m_ctx.getUserTransaction();
            //utx.begin(); 

            cs = conn.prepareCall("{call procCopyFacAccountsSubmission(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");
            cs.setDouble(1,idSubmission.doubleValue());
            cs.setString(2,newCedantCompany);
            cs.setString(3,"FacExchange");
            cs.setString(4,"SBCopyFacAccountBean");
            cs.setString(5,userId);          
            cs.registerOutParameter(6,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);          

            boolean b = cs.execute();   
            int i = cs.getUpdateCount();

            String ErrorMessage = cs.getString(6);
            if ( ErrorMessage != null && !ErrorMessage.equals("") ) {
                throw new GCException( new Exception(ErrorMessage), ErrorMessage, false, false);                
            }

            //utx.commit();
            //utx = null;

        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            GCUtility.errorInfo(e.getMessage());
            throw new GCException( e, "Exception thrown in copyAccount of "+ CLASS_NAME, false, false);
        } finally {
            /*
            if ( utx!= null ) {
                try {
                    utx.rollback();
                } catch ( Exception e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();                    
                    throw new GCException( e, "Exception while rolling back in copyAccount of "+ CLASS_NAME, false, false);
                }
            }
            */
            try {
                if ( cs != null ) cs.close();             
                if ( conn != null ) conn.close();
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                GCUtility.errorInfo(e.getMessage());
                throw new GCException( e, "Exception while closing connection in copyAccount of "+ CLASS_NAME, false, false);
            }
        }               
    }

    private  Double getEBCompany(String cdeCompanyNumber) throws GCException{
        Double uidCompany = null;

        // @@ uncomment this line when eb is ready
        //
        try {               
            EBCompanyHome m_EBCompanyHome = (EBCompanyHome)GCHomesCache.getHome(EBCompanyHome.class,FacConstant.EBCOMPANY_JNDI_URL);  

            EBCompany ebCompany =   m_EBCompanyHome.findByCompanyNumber(cdeCompanyNumber);
            if (ebCompany != null) {
                // @@ line changed
                //uidCompany = ebCompany.getID();
                uidCompany = new Double(ebCompany.getM_uidCompany().doubleValue());
            }

                return uidCompany;
        } catch (ObjectNotFoundException e) {
                return null;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new GCException (e,"Exception in getEBCompany(String cdeCompanyNumber) of copy account process",false,false);
        }
        //
    }                   

    protected Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc.FacExchangeDS");
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }



}
```

I'm using JDeveloper as IDE. I have some doubts about the migration. I can see there are multiple entity beans in the EJB 2.x project. But there are no entity beans in EJB 3.1. What is the purpose of the entity bean and the alternative for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an `ejb-jar.xml` inside your project .ear or .jar, this XML has properties about your EJBs. There should be information about stateless or stateful there. There are other information that you may need in this XML like the remote or home interfaces, links, and the classes names.

Here I have an example:

```
    ...
    ...
    <session>
        <display-name>myEjbExample</display-name> 
        <ejb-name>myEjbExample</ejb-name>
        <home>com.test.myEjbExampleHome</home>
        <remote>com.test.myEjbExampleRemote</remote>
        <ejb-class>com.test.myEjbExample</ejb-class>

        <!-- this tag indicates what you need -->
        <session-type>Stateless</session-type>

        <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
        <ejb-ref>
            <ejb-ref-name>EjbExample</ejb-ref-name>
            <ejb-ref-type>Entity</ejb-ref-type>
            <home>com.test.myEjbExampleHome</home>
            <remote>com.test.myEjbExample</remote>
            <ejb-link>myEjbExample</ejb-link>
        </ejb-ref>
        <resource-ref>
            <res-ref-name>jdbc/myConn</res-ref-name>
            <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
            <res-auth>Application</res-auth>
        </resource-ref>
   </session>
   ...
   ...
```